# ftp/tcp server failing (looping)

Tags: ftp, sles, inetd

I'm getting frequent errors in `/var/log/messages` and the ftp service is getting stopped and started over and over.
I haven't got any clue behind this error message and what is happening during these errors is logged.

```
May  4 04:11:23 node1 inetd[1587]: ftp/tcp server failing (looping), service terminated
May  4 04:51:13 node1 inetd[1587]: ftp/tcp server failing (looping), service terminated
May  8 04:12:10 node1 inetd[1587]: ftp/tcp server failing (looping), service terminated
May 15 04:14:56 node1 inetd[1587]: ftp/tcp server failing (looping), service terminated
May 16 04:15:28 node1 inetd[1587]: ftp/tcp server failing (looping), service terminated
May 16 04:37:38 node1 inetd[1587]: ftp/tcp server failing (looping), service terminated
```

SuSE SLES-8 (i386)
PATCHLEVEL = 4

Could you please any one help me to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 2):

`inetd` is stopping your ftp-service for some reason. This happens a lot when you have too much open connections at any given time. It assumes you are under attach.

Have a look at `/etc/inetd.conf`. There should be an option called `protocol` for the ftp-service followed by a number, try setting this higher.

```
ftp     stream  tcp     nowait/3/10  root    /usr/libexec/ftpd       ftpd -l
```

The `3` stands for the max number of child processes and `10`for the max number of connections. Removing this or changing it to `0` will make this unlimited.

Some FTP clients open a load of separate connections for each transfer, this might cause this behavior.

Don't forget to restart `inetd` after making the changes.

Comment: Yes, but did you need to edit them?

Comment: I have these two lines in inetd.conf. ftp stream tcp nowait root /usr/sbin/tcpd in.ftpd, ftp stream tcp nowait root /usr/sbin/tcpd vsftpd... How will I edit them?